# Omit a character from multiple files in same folder

Tags: powershell

My media files have the following names:

- s01ep01
- S01ep02
- etc.

I need to remove the letter "p" so my program can properly cross reference the episodes.

[image: files to be changed]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It's far easier to edit existing code than to write it from scratch

Comment: um i don't actually know power shell i just googled if there was a way to modify multiple file names in the same directory and was referred to using powershell and this website for help.

Comment: The purpose of this website is to help you with problems in code you wrote, not to write code for you. We usually expect you to have at least a basic understanding of the language you chose, and to have made an effort to solve the problem yourself (show us what you tried and explain what didn't work as expected). Since your question is simple enough I posted an answer anyway, but don't expect this to happen again.

Comment: Fair enough... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```psh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\your\folder' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^(s\d+e)p', '$1' }
```